# Foreign key is null : Hibernate Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I try to save object Run to database. I defined relation between Run and City. One city could have many runs. I got problem with city_id. Is null.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement] with root cause
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'city_id' cannot be null
```

My entieties and controller: 
City

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "cities")
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "city_id")
    private long id;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Run> runs = new ArrayList<>();
    private String name;
}
```

Run

```
@Entity
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "runs")
public class Run {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    @Column(name = "name_run")
    private String nameRun;
    @Column(name = "distance")
    private double distance;
    @Column(name = "date")
    private Date date;
    @Column(name = "my_time")
    private String myTime;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "city_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private City city;
}
```

Controller

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/")
public class RunController {

    private RunRepository runRepository;
    private RunService runService;

    public RunController(RunRepository runRepository, RunService runService) {
        this.runRepository = runRepository;
        this.runService = runService;
    }

    @GetMapping("runs")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Run>> getRuns() {
        return runService.getRuns();
    }

    @PostMapping("runs")
    public ResponseEntity addRun(@RequestBody Run run) {

        return new ResponseEntity<>(runRepository.save(run), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

I would like to save the run in DB. 
My test request looks like :

{
"nameRun":  "test",
"distance":"5.0",
"date":"2020-12-12",
"myTime":"50:40",
"city":"test1"
}

Result from evaluate expresion in Intelijj:

[image]

Why the City = null? Is here error in mapping?

Comment: What database do you use? Could you please provide your `cities` and `runs` tables definition (ddl sql).

Answer (score 1):

Can you try with this json but you need to pass city id in json.

```
{
    "nameRun": "test",
    "distance": "5.0",
    "date": "2020-12-12",
    "myTime": "50:40",
    "city": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test1"
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This request does not work. Sill I got **Column 'city_id' cannot be null**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, use `Long` for id  please. It is better to add `@Entity` annotation too.

```
@Entity
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "city", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Run> runs = new ArrayList<>();

}

@Entity
public class Run {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private City city;

}
```

You need to set `city_id` when you save `Run`.

The simplest way to do that is just create a fake transient `City` and set id to it.

```
City city = new City();
city.setId(1L);

Run run = new Run();
run.setCity(city);

repository.save(run);
```

Obviously you should have a city with `id` 1L in the database.

Other options are

1. Use something like `session.load()` Hibernate analogue with Spring repository to create `City` without loading it from datatbase.
2. Load `City` entity entirely by id.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna save any run class,

```
Run run = new Run();
City city = new City();
city.getRuns().add(run);
runRepository.save(run);
```

if you wanna save any run class, first you need to insert to (Arraylist) runs variable of city class like **city.getRuns().add(run)** after filling run then you can runRepository.save(run).

Also my samples are here. You can look at myclasses.

First class is called **Patient** .

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@ToString
@Table(name = "aapatient")
public class Patient {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AA_PATIENT_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "AA_PATIENT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "AA_PATIENT_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "patientid")
    private Long patientid;
    private String name;
    private String lastname;  

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "patient", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Problem> problems; 
}
```

Second Class called **Problem** is this one.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name="aaproblem")
public class Problem{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "AA_PATIENT_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "AA_PATIENT_SEQ", allocationSize = 1, name = "AA_PATIENT_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "problemid")
    private Long problemid;
    private String problemName;
    private String problemDetail; 

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    Date creationDate;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
    private Patient patient;

}
```